# Unknown Terminal connection

Tags: connector

I am was repairing a micro switch on a PCB that controls a vent hood.  The PCB was connected with this connector.   When I tried to reconnect some of terminal pins broke off.  I have attached two images 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Pitch? Maybe these: https://katalog.we-online.de/de/em/MM_1_27_FEMALE_CONNECTOR_WITH_LATCH_W_O_POLARIZATION_69036719XX72

Comment: Please ask a question. Are you looking to identify the header, the connector, both? Are there pieces missing from your images that were part of the original assembly?

Comment: that is not a pluggable connector

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  To clarify my question.  I am look to identify the PINs and connector so that I can souce and replace the PINS as one broke and some of the others bent

Comment: Also,  why are you saying not a pluggable connection.   The pins should not be soldered to PCB?  Just the ribbon cable with pins snapped on to PCB?

Comment: OK... so here is what I know today.   The Ribbon cable header is not the piece above.  In fact the image  of the red connector is the female connector on the PCB board.  The exposed pins are infact what was in the RED female connector.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Wurth Part [690207100672](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/w-rth-elektronik/690207100672/732-4839-5-ND/4322421) I am not 100% sure this is it without exact measurments, however you are certainly looking for a wire to board connector like that. If that is not the one you can verify pitch of cable and pitch on board and there is one that should work.
[image]